# klocwork issue for std::ofstream open

Tags: c++, ofstream, klocwork

Klocwork throws

> resource acquired to 'ofs.open("file.txt", std::ofstream::out)' may be
>   lost here

for the below piece of code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void main()
{
    std::ofstream ofs;
    ofs.open("file.txt", std::ofstream::out);
    if (ofs.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "file open success\n";
    }
    ofs.close();
}
```

I dont find any issues with the above code. Can someone explain what need to be done here to fix the issue.

Comment: My guess would be "false positive by the tool" - hard to avoid, there's always going to be some of those..

Comment: It might be because a variable is not assigned to the result of `ofs.open("file.txt", std::ofstream::out);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you still having this issue? 
I have a workaround that satisfies Klocwork:
use RAII:

```
std::ofstream ofs( "file.txt", std::ios::binary );
```

If that doesn't work, use a temp.

```
        std::ofstream temp( "file.txt", std::ios::binary );
        if( !temp.is_open() )
        {
            temp.close();
        }
        else
        {
            m_outStream = std::move( temp );
        }
```